# TCL not recognizing C++ Commands NS2

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

For starters, I had this working a week ago before new software was installed on my computer. Files were previously run with `./FileName.tcl` instead of `ns FileName.tcl`. No idea why that changed, but I have not been able to get NS2 files to run the same again.

I added to the NS2 DumbAgent protocol to get energy of nodes. This was done via the following command in dumbagent.cc:

```cpp
int DumbAgent::command(int argc, const char*const* argv)
{
  if (argc == 3) {

//Other pre-built commands 

    else if (strcmp(argv[1], "get_energy") == 0)
    {
        u_int32_t addr = atoi(argv[2]);
        get_energy(addr);
        Node* iNode = Node::get_node_by_address(addr);
        std::cout << iNode << std::endl;
        printf("COMMMAND TEST ");
        iEnergy = iNode->energy_model()->energy();
        std::cout << iEnergy << std::endl;
        return TCL_OK;
    }
  }
  return Agent::command(argc, argv);
}

double DumbAgent::get_energy(u_int32_t addr) 
{

    Node* iNode = Node::get_node_by_address(addr);
    std::cout << iNode << "\n";
    Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();
    printf("FUNCTION TEST ");
    //addr = addr;
    tcl.evalf("puts \"Node Reference from C++: %d \"", addr);

    tcl.evalf("puts \"iNode from C++: %i \"", iNode);
    double iEnergy;
    iEnergy = iNode->energy_model()->energy();

    tcl.evalf("puts \"energy = %d\"", iEnergy);
    return iEnergy;
}
```

Using the proper additions to dumbagent.h, object files, and `make clean, ./configure/pathtoTCL -withVersion=tcl, make` I was able to get all these print statements to spit out what I need - as it took me using all the prints to figure everything out.

However, now, I cannot get anything out. I even added additional prints to the constructor to see what was going on:

```cpp
DumbAgent::DumbAgent() : Agent(PT_PING) {
    printf("TEST TEST TEST");
    std::cout << "Constructor called." << std::endl;
    iEnergy = 0.0;
    bind("energy_otcl", &iEnergy);
    bind("addr_otcl", &addr);
}
```

Nothing - all the DumbAgents and the simulation work. But no output. My Tcl Script calls everything with:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} { incr i} {
    set dumbagent($i) [new Agent/DumbAgent]
    $ns attach-agent $node($i) $dumbagent($i)
}

#$dumbagent(1) get_energy 1

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} { incr i} {
    $dumbagent($i) get_energy $i
    puts "$dumbagent($i), $node($i), $i"
}

#$ns at 19.0 "$dumbagent(2) get_energy 2"
```

Where the first loop, use to print out the constructor items, and the second would print current energy. What is happening here? How can I get my information out?

I know it is calling the correct file because if I completely screw up the dumbagent.cc file, it will not make/configure. I either get no output at all (depending on lines I comment out in Tcl Script) or:

```
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o758" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"$dumbagent($i) get_energy $i"
    ("for" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} { incr i} {
    $dumbagent($i) get_energy $i
    puts "$dumbagent($i), $node($i), $i"
}"
```

What is going on?

Comment: Default is `$ ns FileName.tcl`. ... Any particular reason to do it with ./FileName.tcl ?

Comment: No reason - that is just how I ran things on the computer previously. It is what worked, so I kept with it. Now, I am running the ```ns```

Comment: Looks like the implementations are not being registered as commands/methods, despite being compiled.

Comment: @DonalFellows yes, that is exactly what is happening. The weird thing is, if I completely screw up the C++ file, it will not compile. Therefore, it is running/recognizing the correct file. So, what is the solution?